# How to add element to an Object?

Tags: javascript, html

***JavaScript:***

```
let stock = {
1001: {product: 'Chocolates', cost: 10, quantity: 0},
1002: {product: 'Biscuits', cost: 10, quantity: 0},
1003: {product: 'Bread', cost: 20, quantity: 0},
1004: {product: 'Milk', cost: 25, quantity: 0},
1005: {product: 'Curd', cost: 20, quantity: 0},
```

}

So, on the JavaScript side, I have declared an object, "stock". Now using HTML's prompt as input I want to add the input code, product, cost, and quantity.

***HTML:***

```
<body>
<h1>My Shop</h1>
<label for="numberOfNewProducts" id="numberOfNewProductsLabel">Enter the Number of New Products to be Added: </label>
<br>
<input type="text" id="numberOfNewProducts" value="" placeholder="Enter the number of new Products to be added">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="addButton" onclick="addProduct()">Add</button>
<script src="stock.js"></script>
<script>
    function addProduct(){
        let numberOfNewProducts = document.getElementById("numberOfNewProducts").value;
        Number(numberOfNewProducts);
        number = 0;
        while(number < numberOfNewProducts){
            number++;
            let inputCode = prompt("Entert the Code you want to give to the New Product: ");
            Number(inputCode);
            let inputProductName = prompt("Enter the Name of the New Product: ");
            let inputProductCost = prompt("Enter the Cost of the New Product: ");
            Number(inputProductCost);
            let inputProductQuantity = prompt("Enter the Quantity of the New Product: ");
            Number(inputProductQuantity);
            stock[inputCode].product = inputProductName;
            stock[inputCode].cost = inputProductCost;
            stock[inputCode].quantity = inputProductQuantity;
            console.log(stock);
        }
    }
</script>
```

The end of the while loop is a little perplexed also. 
How do I add the input code and all the products, cost and quantity to the object, "stock"?

Comment: You're not saying what that code is doing wrong right now, forcing everyone to look for a bug without enough information.  Try to provide some more information about the problem you see.
Possibly your problem is related to your use of the Number(value) constructor. Those lines won't do anything other than possibly throw an error, as the Number created is not assigned to any property.  Perhaps you meant : inputCode = Number(inputCode);
You mention being perplexed about the end of the while loop - it will end when the condition evaluates to a 'falsy' value when it's evaluated each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a object like:

```
var obj = {product:"Cookie",cost:10,quantity:0};
```

then add into the `stock` like:

```
stock[inputCode] = obj;
```

Comment: good catch. the existing code will throw an exception without first assigning an object to that key.

Comment: why? @AllanNienhuis

Comment: not your code, the original code the original code that was posted in the question :)